# Does not work in Visual studio but works as .exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a problem with Visual Studio. My code crashes when run using Visual Studio, but works correctly if I compile it and run it as a exe.

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2013 Version 12.0.3.1101.00 Update 4

I am pretty sure it is a Visual Studio setting problem. It is only in some Visual Studio installation I have experienced it in, in other installations this code works fine.

```
class Program
{

    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern int waveOutGetNumDevs();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int numOfDevices = waveOutGetNumDevs(); //<--- throws SEHException 
            Console.WriteLine("Number Of Audio Out Devices: " + numOfDevices);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + exception.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The waveOutGetNumDevs() function throws an exception when I run it from visual Studio, but returns the correct value if I run it as a .exe.
It doesn't matter if I run in debug mode or release mode. Both fail.

The exception I get is:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException occurred
  _HResult=-2147467259
  _message=An external component has thrown an exception.
  HResult=-2147467259
  IsTransient=false
  Message=An external component has thrown an exception.
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  InnerException:
```

Another observation, it depends on what version of .net I am using. 
If I am using .NET 2.0 it actually works correctly, but if I use .NET 4.0 it fails.

My goal is to run the code in .NET 4.0 (later in .NET 4.5).

Edit 1:

The Error code and HResult in HEX is: 0x80004005

Edit 2:

I have now upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5
And the problem still persists.

Comment: But when you compile against .NET 4.0 the executable still works, only in VS it doesn't?

Comment: Correct, If I run the executable compiled against .NET 4.0 it works. But if I debug/release mode inside Visual Studio, it throws the SEHException.

Comment: What's the ErrorCode/HResult on the exception?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Luaan HResult and ErrorCode is both -2147467259

Comment: If you go to the Debug->Windows->Exception Settings and deselect the relevant checkbox does it work then? Could be an exception that gets handled at runtime that your debugger is breaking on.

Comment: @PeterMorris Thanks for the suggestion, but the exception is still throw. I have tried to deselect the said Exception and also tried deselect all exception, but it did not work sadly.

Comment: Check the return type.  It may be returning a different size integer.  Try Uint instead of int.

Comment: Well, that's not very useful. What version of Windows do you have? Have you tried running Visual Studio as an administrator? Are you on a 32-bit system or 64-bit? Is your application running as 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @Luaan I am running windows 32 bit, and everything is target 32-bit. I have tried running Visual Studio as administrator and without administrator. But it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @jdweng I tried it, sadly it didn't help.

Comment: Try to update VS2013 to Update 5.

Comment: @DavidBS thanks for the suggestion, I have now upgraded to Update 5. Sadly the problem still persists.

Comment: try using `long` instead of `int`; `public static extern long waveOutGetNumDevs();`

Comment: @mijail Thanks for the suggestion. But it still is the same error I get. I don't think it is in the PInvoke signature the problem lies. The code works if I run it as a executable, but it throws a SEHException if I run it from inside Visual Studio.

Comment: are you running VS in Administrator mode?

Comment: he already tried that too, seems to be his VS installation or maybe return type, the documentation says `UINT` but the error its something else.

Comment: The problem is not the return type, I get a whole different error if that would be the problem. The code works if I run it as a executable, but not when I run it inside of VS.

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me, in Visual Studio 2012 and .Net Framework 4.5.1:

**Player.cs**

```
class Player
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern uint waveOutGetNumDevs();

    public uint GetNumDevs
    {
        get
        {
            return waveOutGetNumDevs();
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Player player = new Player();
            uint numOfDevices = player.GetNumDevs;
            Console.WriteLine("Number Of Audio Out Devices: " + numOfDevices);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + exception.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm using a property to call the method and th return value's type is `UINT`, here the documentation: [waveOutGetNumDevs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If still not working consider to reinstall your VS2013.

good luck (°-°)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sadly this did not fix my problem. I am pretty sure the error is not in the PInvoke signature, due to it works correctly outside of visual studio, but not when run inside visual studio.